# What is Tyrael after he reforms in the Pandemonium?

Tags: diablo

After the events of Diablo 2, Tyrael is destroyed, having sacrificed himself in order to destroy the Corrupted Worldstone. However, contrary to the normal process of reforming as a new Angel through the Crystal Arch Tyrael instead reformed in the Realm of Pandemonium instead.

<sup>[Source](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Tyrael#Return_to_the_High_Heavens)</sup>

The problem here is that the Realm of Pandemonium is essentially the manifestation of all aspects of Anu, before he separated himself from his negative aspects and forming Tathamet - The Realm of Pandemonium is the "scar of the universe's violent birth", from which all things came.

If Tyrael reformed in this place, rather than through the more "pure" Crystal Arch, would he not become "tainted" by the Realm itself? Could this be the fundamental reason why he separated himself from Heaven in D3? I.e. he was no longer completely an Angel, but rather something else?

I realize this question is bordering on pure speculation, so if necessary, is there any evidence that negates this theory?

---

Post-Edit: Another addition to this theory (though not really anything at this stage since *Diablo: Immortal* is still in Alpha and not much is known about the timeline in that game); Tyrael was "killed" after destroying the Worldstone; which was corrupted by Baal. In *Diablo: Immortal*, the player seeks the shards of the corrupted Worldstone, which still hold immense demonic power. Since Tyrael was engulfed in the initial explosion, no doubt some of that corruption would have mixed in with his "light and hormony".

Comment: Where is that lore coming from, Diablo 2 doesn't say Tyrael died I think? Neither does Diablo 3?

Comment: @kutschkem it's actually from dialogue with Tyrael in the hidden camp in D3 (have added the source)

Comment: Thanks I missed that.